Responsive Form Layout Issues on Small Screen Widths
The form layout works well on most screen sizes, shrinking as expected, but at 260px width, it stops shrinking and starts overflowing the viewport. I've checked the CSS for any fixed widths, padding, and margins but can't identify the problem's cause.
image of contact form
image when it overflows


.contact-us-section {
  margin-bottom: 15rem;
}

.contact-us-title {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.contact-form {
  background-image: url("../content/contact-us-background.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 3rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
}

.two-section-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.two-sections-contact-us {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.two-sections-contact-us.first {
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.contact-label {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.contact-input {
  all: unset;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input-section-cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.input-section-cont.last {
  margin-bottom: 0rem;
}

.message-cont {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.message-input {
  all: unset;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  resize: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.submit-button {
  all: unset;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #ff7315;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 450px;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .contact-label {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
  .submit-button {
    font-size: 1.2;
    padding: 0.8rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .two-section-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .two-sections-contact-us.first {
    padding: 0rem;
  }
  .input-section-cont.last {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }
  .message-input {
    min-height: 200px;
  }
  .submit-button {
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 0.6rem;
    width: 200px;
  }
  .contact-label {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .contact-input {
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }
  .contact-form {
    padding: 1.5rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .submit-button {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.6rem 0;
  }
  .contact-form {
    padding: 1rem;
  }
}
<div class="section contact-us-section">
  <div class="main-container contact-us">
    <h1 class="title contact-us-title">Contact us</h1>
    <form class="contact-form" action="">
      <div class="two-section-container">
        <div class="two-sections-contact-us first">
          <div class="input-section-cont">
            <label class="contact-label" for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="contact-input" />
          </div>
          <div class="input-section-cont">
            <label class="contact-label" for="name">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="contact-input" />
          </div>
          <div class="input-section-cont last">
            <label class="contact-label" for="name">Phone</label>
            <input type="text" class="contact-input" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="two-sections-contact-us second">
          <label for="" class="contact-label">Message</label>
          <textarea name="message" id="message" class="message-input"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="submit-button">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
  </div>



I've removed all fixed widths, switched to percentage-based widths, and minimized padding and margins to prevent overflow. I've also ensured that box-sizing: border-box; is applied to include padding and borders in width calculations, and I've checked for any flexbox issues to make sure containers can wrap or stack items. Despite these efforts, the form still overflows at 260px. I'm not sure what's causing this issue and I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve it.

Cannot reproduce - Please move your code to a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.
